# How do I use .each using html code saved in var and filter it on tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a variable called code with in there html code collected of an other page by the server. I want todo some simple code to filter the data but I dont know how to use jQuery to use the variable (im not really used to using jQuery).

I have used the same code on an other application before, but this time I need to use the code from the var and I don't know how todo that.

```
var code = "loads of html code here";
$(code)('ul .items').each(function(){
                console.log('test');
});
```

that above is not a function but just an example to try to make it clear what I  want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a call to the jQuery find method to search within the html string like this:

```
`var code = '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li class="test">Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>';
$(code).find('li.test').each(function(){
            console.log('test');
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3cpLr9mu/